# avoid duplication of php include/require

Tags: php, performance, include

I have been wondering this for a while, and I have not yet seen the answer in SE.

When using includes in php, my working understanding is that any code that is *included* will be processed by the server.

This would mean that in the following conditional, both large blocks of code are PROCESSED on the server even though only one of these includes will be EMPLOYED.

```
<?php
if($conditional === TRUE){
    include("MASSIVEAMOUNTOFCODE.php");
}
else {
    include("GARGANTUANAMOUNTOFCODE.php");
}
?>
```

(Please pardon the grossly simplified code here.)

I have recently started using the following structure to perform the same task, with the aim of saving processing time on the server. **Please tell me if this loads only a single include file,** or if I am on a fool's errand:

```
<?php
if($conditional === TRUE){
    $includeFile = "MASSIVEAMOUNTOFCODE.php";
}
else {
    $includeFile = "GARGANTUANAMOUNTOFCODE.php";
}

include("$includeFile");
?>
```

Note the double usage of "include" in the first sample, and only a single use of "include" in the second sample.

Comment: I think your original premise is wrong. It only processes one of the `include` lines.

Comment: the inclusion of code is usually handlet pretty well by the precompiler and the bytecode-cache. so using an easier "include-structure" should be the better choice. execution time of the included part is, obviously, only a matter if it's actually executed. so, just as a gut feeling, i'd stick with the first way - but even more, i'd try structuring my code in such a way that i don't have to conditionally include in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original assumption that both files are processed is wrong. An `include` statement inside a code block that's never executed is ignored.

You can see that this is true by putting a syntax error in the include file in the non-executed branch. I did:

testinclude.php:

```
<?php
if (false) 
    include 'badinclude.php';

echo "done\n";
```

badlinclude.php:

```
<?php

$foo =;
```

When I executed `testinclude.php` there was no complaint about the syntax error in `badlinclude.php`. But if I change `if (false)` to `if (true)` I get an error.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in /Users/barmar/badinclude.php on line 3

So the two versions of your code should be equivalent.

Comment: I like this approach, but – with respect – I would love to see the documentation that states the non-executed branch is not compiled.

Comment: How can it compile something with a syntax error in it?

Comment: The point of my demonstration is to show that it doesn't compile the include file. If it did, it would detect an error when there's a syntax error. Unless you think it suppresses errors when the file is in a non-executed branch.

Comment: Yes, Barmar, I understand the point of the demonstration, and I am accepting your answer. Thanking you. If anyone else knows if the documentation exists, please do comment it in here. Thank you.

Comment: I searched the `include` page at the PHP documentation site, it doesn't go into this level of detail. But there's nothing there that suggests that non-executed `include` statements are treated specially. PHP doesn't use a preprocessor like C.

Comment: Good information, Barmar. In the end, your scientific approach beats documentation. I just wish I knew where I inherited this misconception from. :-P

Answer (score -1):

Your assumption is wrong.

What [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) does is that when the function is **called** it will load the file as a new PHP file in the same environment as where it was called from.

Example:

test.php:

```
<?php $test = 'test'; include('test2.php'); ?>
```

test2.php:

```
<?php echo $test; ?>
```

This will output:

```
test
```

Back to the question you asked, it will not process both files, because it can't do both function calls when one is called if something is true, and the other if it isn't. include works just like any other normal functions in that it isn't executed before it's called.

If you want to make sure a file is only included once, or even require it to be loaded once, then use [include_once](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php) or [require_once](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php).